# How to throw django 404 error as error message on the same page

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to query an instance of a particular model, FoodRedistributor and I would like to throw a pop up error message on the same page if a FoodRedistributor of the given name does not exist. I tried doing Http404 but that redirects me to a 404 page which is not how I would like the user to see the error. Using the messages.info does not give me any output.

```
if request.method == "POST":
         username = request.POST.get("username")
         password = request.POST.get("password")
         try:
             user = FoodRedistributor.objects.get(name=username)
         except:
            raise Http404("No food redistributor matches the given query.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are okay with using messages like error

   ```
   if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get("username")
        password = request.POST.get("password")
        try:
            user = FoodRedistributor.objects.get(name=username)
        except:
           errormessage = 'No food redistributor matches the given query.'
           #raise Http404("No food redistributor matches the given query.")

   #render template with errormessage
   ```
2. PASS THE errormessage to the template through the context dictionary and rerender the same page
3. Render the error message in the template if error message exist

   **template.html**

   ```
   <!-- template headers -->

   {% if errormessage  %}
       <p style="color:red;"> {{errormessage}} </span>
   {% endif %}

   <!-- template rest of content-->
   ```

Else you can use JS to create a pop up based on passed error message value